# Excel Vlookup stops Working more than two rows

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a newbie question regarding Excel Vlookup. It works only for two rows. If there are more than two rows. It stopped working.

Data is as follow:

```
2011    0.25
0       1
0       2
0       3
2012    0.39
```

And I wrote =VLOOKUP(2011,A1:B2,2), I got 0.25 as expected. However,if i expand search to the third row, say =VLOOKUP(2011,A1:B3,2), i got 2 instead. What a hack? Anybody?

Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` in approximate-match mode (the default) requires the data to be sorted by the reference column (in your case column A). Sort the data and try again.

Alternatively, you may change the match mode to exact-match by specifying `FALSE` for `range_lookup`. In exact-match mode, the data need not be sorted and can be used as is.

```
=VLOOKUP(2011, A1:B2, 2, FALSE)
```

See [the documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx) for more details. Exact-match mode is probably what you want anyway and IMHO should have been the default.

---

Additionally, you have multiple keys. The behavior of `VLOOKUP(0, ...)` will return the first row with 0. I do not know if this is intended, but you may need to clean up your data first.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wonder though, is there a way that I don't have to sort? I only want to look up 2011 and 2013 etc, so don't worry about the multi-key issue. Appreciate it.

Comment: Check my edit. You can specify `FALSE` for `range_lookup` to change VLOOKUP to exact-match mode. The data doesn't need to be sorted, and this behavior probably matches what you're trying to do anyway. Why this isn't the default mode is beyond me though...